# Dúvida com select html com lista de estados na página de edição. Como preencher?

Tags: php, html

Tenho um formulário que mostra os dados do usuário. Um dos campos é o estado onde ele mora. Pra esse campo, coloquei um "select", e queria que, quando ele abrisse a página, aparecesse no select o estado que está cadastrado no banco de dados. Mas se ele clicar na setinha, abrisse os outros 26 estados para ele poder selecionar e editar.

```
<select class="estado" id="estado" >
    <option value="<?php echo $row_usu['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row_usu['uf']; ?></option>
</select>
```

Quando abro a página, é claro, vai aparecer o select com o estado que está cadastrado no BD, no caso MG. E se eu clicar na setinha, não tem mais nada.

Eu pensei em colocar o select predefinido com a lista dos 27 estados, e trazer o estado que está no banco de dados para uma variável $estado. E aí, quando o sujeito abrir a página, o select aponta automaticamente para aquele estado da variável, mas se clicar, pode alterar.

Como faço isso ?

Answer (score -2):

Enquanto não consigo, estou usando assim:

```
<select class="estado" id="estado" >
    <option value="<?php echo $row_usu['id']; ?>"><?php echo 
    $row_usu['uf']; ?></option>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="AC">AC</option>
    <option value="AL">AL</option>
    <option value="AP">AP</option>
    <option value="AM">AM</option>
    <option value="BA">BA</option>
    <option value="CE">CE</option>
    <option value="DF">DF</option>
    <option value="ES">ES</option>
    <option value="GO">GO</option>
    <option value="MA">MA</option>
    <option value="MS">MS</option>
    <option value="MT">MT</option>
    <option value="MG">MG</option>
    <option value="PA">PA</option>
    <option value="PB">PB</option>
    <option value="PR">PR</option>
    <option value="PE">PE</option>
    <option value="PI">PI</option>
    <option value="RJ">RJ</option>
    <option value="RN">RN</option>
    <option value="RS">RS</option>
    <option value="RO">RO</option>
    <option value="RR">RR</option>
    <option value="SC">SC</option>
    <option value="SP">SP</option>
    <option value="SE">SE</option>
    <option value="TO">TO</option>
    </select>
```

Aí fica o estado que está no BD na primeira linha, um espaço, e a lista dos demais. Mas o estado do BD vai ficar sempre repetido...

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Bom, você pode manter o seu código atual, que está exibindo o estado do usuário:

```
<option value="<?php echo $row_usu['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row_usu['uf']; ?></option>
```

Uma caminho simples e que resolveria o seu problema, seria você criar uma outra query com PHP, puxando todos os estados que você possui no banco de dados, e fazer um loop com PHP, para todos os resultados serem exibidos como `<option></option>`.

Segue um exemplo baseado em seu código:

```
<select class="estado" id="estado" >
<option value="<?php echo $row_usu['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row_usu['uf']; ?></option>

 <?php 

 // Conexão com o banco
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $dbname = "seu_banco";

 // Conexão com o banco de dados
 $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

 // set the PDO error mode to exception
 $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

 // Query para preencher select
 $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM sua_tabela");
 $query->execute(array());

 // Fazendo loop no registros, para lista-los
 while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
     echo "<option value = ".$row['id']."> ".$row['uf']." </option>";
 }

 ?>
</select>
```

Neste exemplo, estou utilizando PHP [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdo.php) que funcionária perfeitamente também.

> Eu coloquei o código completo, com a conexão do banco de dados, query e etc... mas como você já está conseguindo mostrar o estado do usuário que vem do banco de dados, acredito que você não irá precisar utilizar o meu exemplo, apenas a parte do **loop**. Porém, irei deixar, para futuras dúvidas, caso tenha.